# QT Creator : how to compile changes only

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator

No idea what might have changed in my QT Creator options or project options, but for some reason doing a Build (Ctrl-B) or starting a debugging session (F5) now triggers a complete rebuild of my project, which takes several minutes. I'd like it to build only the changed files (and dependencies) as it has always done before. What did I do wrong?
I played with the settings "always build before deploying" and "always deploy before running", but changing these just switches between doing no build at all, or doing a full rebuild. How can I (re)activate a "differential" build ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Show your project_name.pro.user file, which contains all the settings you've done to your project setup.

Comment: not sure how I can use attachments here - the file content is too big to copy-and-paste. I simply deleted the .pro.user file in order to have a fresh copy created. No change. The only build step is qmake.exe "... .pro" -r -spec win32-g++

Comment: You can see textual build log in Output panes, select the pane with the name "4 Compile Output". You may want to share its content. Clean the pane, run rebuild, and then copy output. http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html#compile-output

Comment: thanks for your input divanov! I analyzed the build output and then I realized that a small code change didn't actually trigger a rebuild as I first thought. It triggers a build of all "dependent" source files. The application has grown substantially over time, and due to the application structure (MVC with one main window and a large central controller class) it looks like the number of dependencies has grown too big. Time for a thorough rethinking of the app structure which puts less burden on the compiler... Thanks for making me realize this, and sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: I had the same issue recently, but found a solution on another forum. The problem was my system dateTime was one month behind the current date. When I changed, it only compiled the changed ones. Anyone knows the reason why it behaved like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want rebuild project, you can run `qmake` from qt-creator menu and start `build`.
If you have a good computer, you can write to `make` `-j` option, your rebuild time reduce about 3-4 times.

Comment: In Qt Creator you may add custom steps to Build. If one adds "make clean" as this custom step to build, then it will force Qt Creator to remove all binaries and then build them again every time.

Comment: Sure, but by default, Qt Creator has 2 build steps: qmake and make. About "make clean" you can find into 'clean steps'.
Then, single variant for 'rebuild', when run 'build' was rewrote main build steps for 'build' option. (Author shaked build steps)

Comment: Thank you so much, Ruu. You definitely made my day with the "-j" suggestion. Before, the slightest code change caused a compile time of 110 seconds. I added the -j option to the makefile, now the same recompile takes 28 seconds! 4x faster indeed, this makes things workable again. CPU goes from taking only 13% to taking the full 100%, that's what he was paid for ;-)

Comment: Do you want to say, that after changes in one .cpp file single job build takes 110 seconds? I don't know what kind of CPU your have and what is code lines count, but this sounds too much. If you change header file, then it should cause rebuild of all source files including it and this could mean you have excessive includes.

Comment: CPU = i7-2670 QuadCore , project = 72 cpp files + 34 forms, the application is the one you can download here: http://www.gordius.be/midi-footcontroller-downloads.php  It's an application with one complex main window (consisting of many sub-controls), which processes one complex setup (consisting of many data subclasses). I will check how I can decrease the number of cascading includes.

Comment: Where to change this in project configuration?